# Simple Procedure raise ORA-06502

Tags: plsql

There's the simplified version of my code who keep raise me ORA-06502:

```
declare     
    p_filter     varchar2(300) := '2012';
    p_value      varchar2(300) := '12345.000'; 
    w_new_value  number(13,3)  := null ;
    w_count      number(4)     := null ;   
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) 
      INTO w_count
      FROM dual
      where p_filter = p_filter;
      --- more filters
    if w_count != 0 then
      w_new_value := p_value / w_count;
   else
      w_new_value := p_value;
   end if;       

   -- do something

end;
/
```

Someone can give me a help?

### DataBase Details

> - nls_language            = italian
> - nls_territory           = italy
> - nls_currency            = �
> - nls_iso_currency        = italy
> - nls_numeric_characters  = ,.
> - nls_calendar            = gregorian
> - nls_date_format         = dd-mon-rr
> - nls_date_language       = italian
> - nls_characterset        = we8iso8859p15
> - nls_sort                = west_european
> - nls_time_format         = hh24:mi:ssxff
> - nls_timestamp_format    = dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ssxff
> - nls_time_tz_format      = hh24:mi:ssxff tzr
> - nls_timestamp_tz_format = dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ssxff tzr
> - nls_dual_currency       = �
> - nls_nchar_characterset  = al16utf16
> - nls_comp                = binary
> - nls_length_semantics    = byte
> - nls_nchar_conv_excp     = false

Comment: Why is p_value a varchar?

Comment: because in my real procedure it's passed by java in type String

Comment: Well convert it or pass the right type from Java.

Comment: it's my company framework working like that, not my own code

Comment: What's preventing you from doing the conversion in your procedure?

Comment: because `to_number` function throws ORA-01722....

Comment: Your input data has a string that can't be converted into a number. Your example here fails to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the ansewer and i think is useful for other know.

The real problem of the script for my DB is the language.
The italian "version" of Oracle accept `,` instead of the `.` for translate the `VARCHAR2` into `NUMBER` unlike the most of other country.

For make the code running well the solution is
`w_new_value := replace(p_value,'.',',') / w_count;`

This trick finally allows the DB use my `VARCHAR2` param like a `NUMBER`

Comment: Wow, being a single-verbal-language American, that would **not** have come to me!  But I've learned 13 development languages/platforms in my career, so that's gotta be good for something, eh?

Glad you found a solution.

Can I get a little credit for giving help?  I could use the points.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is **always** going return a value of 1.

```
SELECT count(*) 
      INTO w_count
      FROM dual
```

It doesn't matter what the qualifier is.

Lastly, I just ran your simplified code example in Oracle 11R2 and it didn't throw an exception.

I added the following statement in place of your "do something" comment:

```
dbms_output.put_line('w_new_value: ' || w_new_value || '. w_count: ' || w_count);
```

The result was:

```
w_new_value: 12345. w_count: 1
```

So, I think you've simplified your example into oblivion.  You need to provide something that actually shows the error.

Good luck.

Comment: I know the count from dual always return a value of 1... but it was an example. If i lanch exactly that code on SQL+ it throws the ORA error...